# Index capitalization

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, uppercase

I want to create a function that capitalizes a string according to the array that is provided. My current function takes in 2 arguments: the string you want to change and an array which would correspond to the letters you want to change. My function looks like so:

```
def capitalize(s, ind):
    for i in ind:
        try:
            s = s.replace(s[i], s[i].upper())
        except IndexError:
            print("Sorry, index is not range!")
    return s
```

This function seemed to work at first, when I tried a few examples such as:

```
capitalize("abc",[1,2])
#Output: aBC
```

However, I cannot work out why this example fails:

```
capitalize("abracadabra",[2,6,9,10])
#Output: AbRAcADAbRA - should be abRAcADAbRA
```

Why is my first letter suddenly becoming capitalized? Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: `str.replace` replaces all occurences of its first argument by default.

Comment: the `replace function` is replacing all the elements of `s` that are the same as 's[i]'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.replace` replaces the first match it finds. So `s.replace(s[10], s[10].upper())` (which is an `a`), won't replace the `a` at index 10, but the first `a` it finds in the string.

Instead, convert your string to a list:

```
import sys

def capitalize(s, ind):
    split_s = list(s)
    for i in ind:
        try:
            split_s[i] = split_s[i].upper()
        except IndexError:
            print(f"Sorry, index is not in range! ({i})", file=sys.stderr)
    return "".join(split_s)

print(capitalize("abracadabra",[2,6,9,10,50]))
```

Output:

> Sorry, index is not in range! (50)
>
> abRacaDabRA

Comment: Thanks! Should have thought about making a list!